# Nested hash parameters in URL - CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

How shall I pass nested hash params into URL for CGI script?
Data:

```
my $params = {
    pwd => 'abc',
    usr => 'abb',
    data => { xyz => 'xxx' },
};
```

I tried:

```
<URI>?pwd=abc&usr=abb&data[xyz]='xxx'
```

But this results into:

```
$VAR1 = { 
   'data[yxz]'     => 'xxx',
   'pwd'           => 'abc',
   'usr'           => 'abb'
}
```

Thanks for any hints.

Note: OK, I can parse string 'data[yxz]' and transform whole pair into hashref, but I am wondering if there is any 'native' function for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

There is no *native way* to do that. If you are using [CGI.pm](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-names-of-all-the-parameters-passed-to-your-script), then you can pass multiple parameters with the same name and fetch them all into an array.

```
GET /?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3
```

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $q = CGI->new;
my @foo = $q->multi_param('foo');

print Dumper \@foo;
```

You will achieve this kind of behavior from an HTML form by having multiple input fields with the same `name` attribute. But that does not give you a hash.

---

To pass along an actual data structure, that is not enough though.
You could encode your multi-dimensional parameters as JSON.

```
<URI>?pwd=abc&usr=abb&data={'yxz':'xxx'}
```

Correctly URL-encoded that would be the following.

```
?pwd=abc&usr=abb&data=%7B%27yxz%27%3A%27xxx%27%7D
```

In your application, you can just convert it from JSON to a Perl data structure using the [JSON](https://v1.metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think it matters for this question whether CGI.pm is in core or not. Bu I'll elaborate what I meant.

Comment: Using JSON instead of the data format the question is asking about means changing from a format which you can generate with an HTML form to one that you cannot.

Comment: @Quenin I don't think OP wants that data format. They just tried it. They are talking about a Perl hashref first after all.

Comment: Whether they are strongly tied to the PHP-style format or not, it doesn't change the fact that the one they are using can be generated with a regular HTML form while JSON cannot.

Comment: I know how to pass multiple paramaters. I was specifically asking about hashref, because i need to pass these args into a module that handles web-service (incomming) data. Application I use is capable to decode REST call with args in JSON format. (And I know how to call it.) I just needed to know wheter it is possibe to encode nested hash ref in URL or not. Your example with JSON is fine, but it presumes that you will hardcode which arguments are in specific format - and I woud like to avoid that. Thx for you effort.

Comment: @JMa what kind of data is this? Is it meta-data for a GET operation that is just reading? Like how to sort, or how to authenticate?

Comment: Yes, it is data for GET operation. Web service returns some data based on paramater placed in 'data' section.

Comment: I have tried to reduce the question and put it as simpe as possible. Your answer 'NO' was absolutely fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

The query string is just a string. You can encode the data any way you like and use any parser you like to convert it into a data structure.

Most parsers will give you a hash of key/value pairs, and inflate any with the same name into an array. This has been the common way Perl (and most programming languages) have handled it pretty much forever.

If you want the extended data structure format that PHP uses, then you'll need to use a parser designed to handle that format.

As usual, [CPAN to the rescue](https://metacpan.org/pod/PHP::ParseStr).

```
use PHP::ParseStr qw(php_parse_str);
my $data = php_parse_str($ENV{QUERY_STRING});
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I didn´t know this module. I don´t want to change the parser right now but maybe I will use it in future.